# How to get disk information on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, disk, read-write

The purpose is to obtain information about the physical hard disk under the Linux platform. The required information includes the **physical hard drive name** (caption), **device path** (such as `/dev/sda`), **read/write rate** and **read and write throughput** of each physical disk, **total disk capacity** and **remaining available capacity** per physical disk. I eventually need to get this information in the program in C++. But I also accept the command line acquisition method.

I have tried `lshw`, `smartctl`, `hdparm`, `lsblk`, `fdisk`.etc, but some of these commands are not available on different Linux distributions. And these methods can't get all the information I want. I also tried to get information from `/proc/diskstats`, `/sys/block`, etc., but it didn't solve the problem. The confusion between logical disks and physical disks also makes processing difficult. It is important to emphasize that the information you need to obtain is for each physical disk.

Comment: this question is probably off topic, but on system where smarctl and other tools are working, you can use `strace` to see where info is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

**fdisk -l** command  will show you in details.